# eval error when using "if" short form

Tags: php, eval, parse-error

when doing something like

```
$date = mktime();
$xxx = 'if ( date("N",$date ) == 1 ) { return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }';
$yyy = eval( $xxx );
echo $yyy;
```

it works.

But when doing something like

```
$date = mktime();
$xxx = '( date("N",$date) == 1 ? return TRUE : return FALSE );';
$yyy = eval( $xxx );
echo $yyy;
```

I get an error like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /my_path/my_file.php(107) : eval()'d code on line 1

Why ?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing at all to do with `eval`.

Let's create the *real* testcase:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
   $date = mktime();
   ( date("N",$date) == 1 ? return TRUE : return FALSE );
}

foo();
?>
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/8rhnHHeF):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN on line 5
```

`return` is a statement, not an expression, so you can't nest it into an expression which is what you're trying to do here. The conditional operator is not a one-line replacement for `if`/`else`.

To use the conditional operator properly:

```
return (date("N",$date) == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE);
```

which simplifies to just:

```
return (date("N",$date) == 1);
```

In your code, that looks like this:

```
$date = mktime();
$xxx = 'return (date("N",$date) == 1);';
$yyy = eval($xxx);
echo $yyy;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty certain that should be

```
$xxx = 'return ( date("N",$date) == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE );';
```

The things generated by a ternary operator are values (expressions) rather than commands.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I do not see the forest because of all the trees ;-)